# Inconsistent output from Pandas apply function with np.std as function parameter

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I am using `sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler` to re-scale my data. I want to use `np.std` to do the same thing with `StandardScaler`.

However, I find an interesting thing that, with no additional parameter passing in `pandas.apply(fun = np.std)` , the outputs varies between sample std and population std. (See 2 Problem)

I know there is a parameter called `ddof` which control the divisor when calculating sample variance.Without changing default parameter `ddof = 0`, how could I get different output!

### 1 Dataset:

First, I choose iris dataset as an example. I scale the first column of my data as follows.

```
from sklearn import datasets
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X_train = iris.data[:,[1]] # my X_train is the first column if iris data
sc = StandardScaler() 
sc.fit(X_train) # Using StandardScaler to scale it!
```

### 2 Problem: with no change to default `ddof = 0` I got different output of np.std!

```
import pandas as pd
import sys
print("The mean and std(sample std) of X_train is :")
print(pd.DataFrame(X_train).apply([np.mean,np.std],axis = 0),"\n")

print("The std(population std) of X_train is :")
print(pd.DataFrame(X_train).apply(np.std,axis = 0),"\n") 

print("The std(population std) of X_train is :","{0:.6f}".format(sc.scale_[0]),'\n') 

print("Python version:",sys.version,
      "\npandas version:",pd.__version__,
      "\nsklearn version:",sklearn.__version__)
```

Out:

```
The mean and std(sample std) of X_train is :
             0
mean  3.057333
std   0.435866 

The std(population std) of X_train is :
0    0.434411
dtype: float64 

The std(population std) of X_train is : 0.434411 

Python version: 3.7.1 (default, Dec 10 2018, 22:54:23) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] 
pandas version: 0.23.4 
sklearn version: 0.20.1
```

From above results, `pd.DataFrame(X_train).apply([np.mean,np.std],axis = 0)` gives sample std 0.435866 while `pd.DataFrame(X_train).apply(np.std,axis = 0)` gives population std 0.434411.

### 3 My questions:

1. Why using `pandas.apply` return different results?
2. How can I pass an additional parameter to `np.std`, which gives population std?

`pd.DataFrame(X_train).apply(np.std,ddof = 1)` can do it. But I am wondering that `pd.DataFrame(X_train).apply([np.mean,np.std],**args)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this behaviour can be found in the (perhaps inelegant) evaluation of `.apply()` on a Series. If you have a [look at the source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/series.py), you'll find the following lines:

```
if isinstance(func, (list, dict)):
    return self.aggregate(func, *args, **kwds)
```

That means: if you call `apply([func])`, the results *can differ* from `apply(func)`!
With regards to `np.std`, I'd suggest to use the builtin `df.std()` methods or perhaps `df.describe()`.

You can try out the following code in order to understand what works and what doesn't:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

print(10*"-","Showing ddof impact",10*"-")

print(np.std([4,5], ddof=0)) # 0.5      ## N   (population's standard deviation)
print(np.std([4,5], ddof=1)) # 0.707... # N-1 (unbiased sample variance)

x = pd.Series([4,5])

print(10*"-","calling builtin .std() on Series",10*"-")
print(x.std(ddof=0)) # 0.5
print(x.std()) # 0.707

df=pd.DataFrame([[4,5],[5,6]], columns=['A', 'B'])

print(10*"-","calling builtin .std() on DF",10*"-")

print(df["A"].std(ddof=0))# 0.5
print(df["B"].std(ddof=0))# 0.5
print(df["A"].std())# 0.707
print(df["B"].std())# 0.707

print(10*"-","applying np.std to whole DF",10*"-")
print(df.apply(np.std,ddof=0)) # A = 0.5,  B = 0.5
print(df.apply(np.std,ddof=1)) # A = 0.707 B = 0.707

# print(10*"-","applying [np.std] to whole DF WONT work",10*"-")
# print(df.apply([np.std],axis=0,ddof=0)) ## this WONT Work
# print(df.apply([np.std],axis=0,ddof=1)) ## this WONT Work

print(10*"-","applying [np.std] to DF columns",10*"-")
print(df["A"].apply([np.std])) # 0.707
print(df["A"].apply([np.std],ddof=1)) # 0.707

print(10*"-","applying np.std to DF columns",10*"-")
print(df["A"].apply(np.std)) # 0: 0 1: 0 WHOOPS !! #<---------------------
print(30*"-")
```

You can also figure out what's happening by `apply`ing your own function:

```
def myFun(a):
    print(type(a))
    return np.std(a,ddof=0)

print("> 0",20*"-")    
print(x.apply(myFun))
print("> 1",20*"-","## <- only this will be applied to the Series!")
print(df.apply(myFun))
print("> 2",20*"-","## <- this will be applied to each Int!")
print(df.apply([myFun]))
print("> 3",20*"-")
print(df["A"].apply(myFun))
print("> 4",20*"-")
print(df["A"].apply([myFun]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you replace 
below

```
print(pd.DataFrame(X_train).apply(np.std,axis = 0),"\n")
```

with this

```
print(pd.DataFrame(X_train).apply([np.std],axis = 0),"\n")
```

Comment: Thanks! But it cannot answer my questions